# Get upper level key from value in a nested JSON object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

If I know the value `Africola` for key `name` in the nested JSON below, how can I get its corresponding upper level key '**barID1**' in JavaScript?

```
{
  "barID1": {
    "address": "4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    "description": “description text”,
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1”,  "https:url2”, "https:url3” ],
    "lat": -34.810585,
    "lon": 138.616739,
    "name": "Africola",
    "phone": "(08) 8223 3885",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url”
  },
  "barID2": {
    "address": "138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
     "description": “description text”,
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1”,  "https:url2”, "https:url3” ],
    "lat": -34.848082,
    "lon": 138.599813,
    "name": "Disco Mexico Taqueria",
    "phone": "0416 855 108",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url”
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in conjuntion with [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like on next example:

```js
const input = {
  "barID1": {
    "address": "4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    "lat": -34.810585,
    "lon": 138.616739,
    "name": "Africola",
    "phone": "(08) 8223 3885",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  },
  "barID2": {
    "address": "138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
     "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    "lat": -34.848082,
    "lon": 138.599813,
    "name": "Disco Mexico Taqueria",
    "phone": "0416 855 108",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  }
};

let [key, val] = Object.entries(input).find(
    ([k, v]) => v.name === "Africola"
);

console.log("key is :", key);
console.log("value is :", val);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, you JSON was malformed with invalid characters.
Use find on keys

```js
let obj = {
  "barID1": {
    "address": "4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    "lat": -34.810585,
    "lon": 138.616739,
    "name": "Africola",
    "phone": "(08) 8223 3885",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  },
  "barID2": {
    "address": "138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
     "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    "lat": -34.848082,
    "lon": 138.599813,
    "name": "Disco Mexico Taqueria",
    "phone": "0416 855 108",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  }
};

let result = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key].name === "Africola");
console.log(result);
```

As a function:

```js
let obj = {
  "barID1": {
    "address": "4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    "lat": -34.810585,
    "lon": 138.616739,
    "name": "Africola",
    "phone": "(08) 8223 3885",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  },
  "barID2": {
    "address": "138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
     "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    "lat": -34.848082,
    "lon": 138.599813,
    "name": "Disco Mexico Taqueria",
    "phone": "0416 855 108",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  }
};

const findKeyByName = (obj, search) => Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key].name === search);

console.log(findKeyByName(obj, 'Africola'));
console.log(findKeyByName(obj,'Disco Mexico Taqueria'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for this.

```
const data = {
  "barID1": {
    "address": "4 East Terrace, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
    "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    "lat": -34.810585,
    "lon": 138.616739,
    "name": "Africola",
    "phone": "(08) 8223 3885",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  },
  "barID2": {
    "address": "138/140 Gouger St, Sydney NSW 2000",
    "appStoreURL": "http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX",
     "description": "description text",
    "imgURLs": [ "Https:url1",  "https:url2", "https:url3" ],
    "lat": -34.848082,
    "lon": 138.599813,
    "name": "Disco Mexico Taqueria",
    "phone": "0416 855 108",
    "status": "active",
    "venueImgURL": "https:url"
  }
};

const [key, obj] = Object.entries(data).find(([key, obj]) => {
  return obj.name === 'Africola';
});

console.log(key, obj);
```

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/zty6fgcp/